# Toggle attr of svg with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, svg, toggle, attr

I understand that I cannot use addClass or removeClass with SVG and that I must use attr.  But how can I toggle an attr of an SVG using jQuery.  See my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2ay12hz/). I am trying to toggle the rotation of the arrow on click (see the commented out portion of the click function in my js section).  Anybody have a better idea of how to do this?

My html

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 sidebar">
                <div class="title-region">
                    <a href="">Current Page</a>
                    <svg class="down-arrow mobile-only" width="17px" height="10px">
                        <use xlink:href="#down-arrow"></use>
                    </svg><!--end hamburger-->
                </div><!--end title-region-->
                <div class="mobile-zipped">
                    <ul class="sidebar-block children">
                        <li><a href="">Child One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Child Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Child Three</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="sidebar-block siblings">
                        <li><a href="">Sibling One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Sibling Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Sibling Three with a super long title</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Sibling Four</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--end mobile-zipped-->
            </div><!--end sidebar-->
```

CSS:

```
    .sidebar {
  position: relative;
  /*width:270px*/
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  /*margin-right:60px;max-width:25%*/
}

.sidebar .title-region {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  background: #005DAA;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-block {
  padding: 15px;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sidebar .down-arrow {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 8px;
  fill: #00305e;
}
```

JS is included in the fiddle.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Better idea than what? I don't see any code toggling an attribute with `attr` above. I see a bunch of at-best-tangentially-related CSS and markup...

Comment: Please see the fiddle

Comment: The content of your question goes **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. A fiddle is an adjunct, not a substitute, for having the relevant code/markup in the question. (Although these days you're usually better off using Stack Snippets, the `<>` button unless you need something jsFiddle has that SS don't.)

Comment: Sorry about that, will keep it in mind for future.  Thank you for your help

Comment: Please edit the relevant code into the question (and remove the irrelevant CSS). Temember, SO isn't here just for you, now. It's here for others, later -- in fact, that's its *primary* purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/x2ay12hz/7/).

```
var classNames = accordionArrow.attr('class').split(' ');
if ($.inArray("flipped", classNames) != -1) {
    //jQuery.grep() to remove duplicates even if multiple occurrences present
    classNames = $.grep(classNames, function (element) {
        return element !== "flipped";
    });
} else {
    classNames.push("flipped");
}
accordionArrow.attr('class', classNames.join(' '));
```

Comment: That's going to be fairly fragile; for instance, if you later edit the markup and add an unrelated class, or even just change the order of the classes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if I split class attribute to array and then find `flipped`, then we'll be fine, right?

Comment: That's one way, yeah.

Comment: @user3633970 a change is made in the answer. Its better than the initial solution.

Comment: So now, if I add a class to the element later adding a new feature, the first time this code runs it blows away that new class.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to add/remove a `flipped` class on `accordianArrow`, you can use the old-fashioned way of dealing with classes:

```
var flipped = /\bflipped\b/;
var cls = accordianArrow.attr("class");
var updated = cls.replace(flipped, '');
if (cls === updated) {
    // Didn't have it; add it
    cls += " flipped";
} else {
    // We removed it, don't leave dangling whitespace (though it doesn't really matter, you could leave this off)
    cls = $.trim(cls);
}
accordianArrow.attr("class", cls);
```